# Is it valid to send a HTML response containing only a script tag

Tags: html

sometimes in "beginner" server-side scripting examples you might see something like

response.write("window.location='xxxx'")

in other words they are sending an HTML response consisting only of a script tag (no head, body etc.). Whilst I'm happy to believe this would work in most browsers most of the time, I can't see any way that it's allowed by HTML standards. Is there some special get-out clause which makes this form valid?

Comment: May I ask if you mean a normal http request? .. to get a html page? ... or by a client side script, like an ajax request?

Comment: yes, i'm talking about a normal browser "get"

Comment: In addition to Quentin's answer, here is some more reading https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not valid. An HTML document requires, at minimum, a Doctype, a head element containing a title and a body. Browsers are very good at recovering from invalid code though.

A redirect should be implemented at the HTTP level with a Location response header.